# Invalid cast from 'Boolean' to 'Datetime' - insert datetime column to database

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, excel, datetime

For 2 days I'd like to write code which imports data from MS excel (Office 365) to datagridview then to mysql database. In this case i have table in ms excel the sheet:

[image]

**What i've done?**

I've already written code which downloads data from ms excel sheet to datagridview and display them.

Now I'm trying insert all data to mysql database. I'm focusing on piece of code in below:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < datagrdStatus_order.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {
                        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT IGNORE INTO try1.order_status(ID_WORKER, ID_ORDER, ID_MODULE, ID_PROJECT, AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, BEGIN_DATE, END_DATE) SELECT workers.ID_WORKER, orders.ID_ORDER, module.ID_MODULE, projects.ID, @AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS, @BEGIN_DATE, @END_DATE FROM try1.workers INNER JOIN try1.orders INNER JOIN try1.modules INNER JOIN try1.projects WHERE workers.FNAME = @FNAME AND workers.LNAME = @LNAME AND workers.ID_WORKER = @ID_WORKER AND orders.ORDER_DESC = @ORDER_DESC AND orders.ORDER_NUMBER = @ORDER_NUMBER AND modules.NAME = @MODULES_NAME AND projects.PROJECT_NAME = @PROJECT_NAME", connection);

                        DateTime begin_date;

                        bool value = DateTime.TryParse(datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString(), out begin_date);

                        if (!value)
                        {
                            begin_date = Convert.ToDateTime(value);
                        }

                        DateTime end_date;

                        bool value2 = DateTime.TryParse(datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value.ToString(), out end_date);

                        if (!value2)
                        {
                           end_date = Convert.ToDateTime(value2);
                        }

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID_WORKER", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FNAME", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LNAME", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ORDER_DESC", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NUMBER_ORDER", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MODULES_NAME", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PROJECT_NAME", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AMOUNT_OF_PRODUCTS", datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BEGIN_DATE", begin_date);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@END_DATE", end_date);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
```

Then i compiled that code, i have an exception:

> Invalid cast from 'Boolean' to 'Datetime'

and points it at the code line:

```
 begin_date = Convert.ToDateTime(value);
```

I was searching for another solutions but i don't still know how to solve it. Any ideas? Thx for any help.

Comment: How is a `true` or `false` value supposed to represent a `DateTime`?

Comment: You should take the proper time to debug your own code rather than ask us to debug it for you

Comment: You should use `end_date` in your `ToDateTime` method, **not** value. `DateTime.TryParse` method returns `boolean` value if your string is valid `DateTime` or not. If your string is valid `DateTime`, it assings the **second parameter** to that value which is `end_date` in your case. You could solve your problem with an easy debugging by the way. I suggest you to read Eric Lippert's https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ article.

Answer (score -1):

You have `value` as a bool type

```
 bool value = DateTime.TryParse(datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString(), out begin_date);
```

Then you call this: `Convert.ToDateTime(value);`
So it throw exeption because `Convert.ToDateTime()` take in a `DateTime` data type not a `bool` type.

Answer (score -1):

What you are trying to do is check if `DateTime` has value correct?

The solution is simple. u should use `DateTime?` instead of `bool` for your `value` variable. This presents a `Nullable DateTime`

Answer (score -1):

*DateTime.TryParse* just returns a bool, if the Parse was successful. The "out" parameter is the return value, what should be interesting.

Both ifs looks unnecessary to me. When *DateTime.TryParse* returns false, you can't parse the string into datetime. You should look what *datagrdStatus_order.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value.ToString()* gives you and if this can be parsed into DateTime.

Maybe the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) should be more clear